# How to get an absolute URL hyperlink path with router-link in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I use the router-link to form a hyperlink in Vue, like as shown below.

```
<template v-slot:cell(id)="data">
   <router-link :to="`twitter.com/all/status/${data.value}`">{{ data.value }}
   </router-link>
 </template>
```

It appends the URL to my site, like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/twitter.com/all/status/1352388073145958402
```

How can I have an absolute URL path instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by not using router-link at all. Like this.

```
<template v-slot:cell(id)="data">
    <a :href="`https://twitter.com/all/status/${data.value}`">{{ data.value }}</a>
</template>
```